# DataTable to the set of SQL queries

Tags: c#, ado.net

How can I convert data from DataTable to the set of SQL queries?

The problem is that I haven't connection with DB.

I've tried:

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

dataAdapter.InsertCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
//Exception - The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized.

dataAdapter.Update(_myDB, MenuTable);
dataAdapter.InsertCommand // contain commands
```

But it's not work, because I haven't connection! Any one have idea?

Comment: I don't think anything ready-made exists for this - you'll have to loop over the rows in your data table and generate the appropriate INSERT statements yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetInsertQueryFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var s = new StringBuilder(string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} SET ", dataTable.TableName));

            foreach (DataColumn v in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                var r = new StringBuilder(row[v.ColumnName].ToString());
                r.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
                r.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
                s.AppendFormat("{0}=\"{1}\", ", v.ColumnName, r);
            }

            s.Remove(s.Length - 2, 1);
            s.AppendLine(";");
            yield return s.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the connection string in the constructor of dataAdapater.  Plus, I think you need to call the Fill method first before updating when using an Adapter.

Comment: The problem is that I haven't connection with DB.

Comment: Then make a connection string.  What's the problem?